# Pretty way to say "foo not in {bar, baz}" in C++11/14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm writing C++ and missing the clarity of Python. But I know that C++ has been evolving and wondering if there's a nicer way to do something like this:

```
if (foo != bar && foo != baz)
```

In Python I would do this:

```
if foo not in {bar, baz}:
```

Is there a fancy feature in C++11 or C++14 that allows me to do something similarly readable?

Edit: A lot of people are wondering why I'm trying to replace something so short. I'm not, but I didn't want to make my example as ugly and unreadable as the original code. It's more like:

```
if (somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname() !=
    SomeReallyLongNamespace::AndAnotherSubClassname::A_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME &&
    somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname() !=
    SomeReallyLongNamespace::AndAnotherSubClassname::ANOTHER_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME) {
    // foo
```

Comment: Any concise way to do it will probably be longer than the plain conjunction of two comparisons. Of course, there is always a point at which the number of comparisons exceeds some other concise way in length.

Comment: @guidoism I think that your real problem is not the `if`-syntax but what it's comparing. I've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37887522/2642059) to help you try to clean some of that up.

Comment: Why not `if([&]{for(auto &&x : { bar, baz }) if(foo == x) return true; return false;}())`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I mean are you saying that over `if(foo != bar && foo != baz)`?

Comment: @JonathanMee obviously, yes. Compared to the 20+ lines solution of the current top-voted answer, my comment-solution is rather concise.

Comment: All the answers that use a std::set seem pretty expansive.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I just wanted to double check that you weren't proposing that for everyday use. Cause I don't think it's possible to beat `if(foo != bar && foo != baz)` for clarity and concision.

Comment: @Benoît Both Python and C++ really need a temporary container to compare against. Using a `set` makes a lot of sense in that it is designed around the premise of only allowing one of each entry, so it scales very well. I'm not sure what the compiler would do with it, but it's just really hard to beat `if(set<int>{bar, baz}.insert(foo).second)` for simplicity.

Answer (score 10):

How about something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename ...Args> struct InT: std::tuple<Args...>
{
    template <typename ...Brgs>
    explicit InT(Brgs &&... brgs)
    : std::tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Brgs>(brgs)...) {}

    template <typename T, std::size_t ...I>
    bool noteq(T && t, std::index_sequence<I...>) const
    {
        return (true && ... && (t != std::get<I>(*this)));
    }
};

template <typename ...Args>
InT<Args &&...> AnyOf(Args &&... args)
{
    return InT<Args &&...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
bool operator!=(T && t, InT<Args...> in)
{
    return in.noteq(std::forward<T>(t), std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```

Usage:

```
if (x != AnyOf(1, 3, 5)) { f(); }
```

Comment: if you rename `In` to `AnyOf` then reading it flows better "x does not equal any of 1, 3, 5"

Comment: Note that this code is not C++14 (fold expressions).

Comment: Might as well add `if (x == AnyOf(1, 3, 5))`

Comment: @Columbo: Yes, I was too lazy to type it out the old way. Exercise for the (ageing) reader.

Comment: Anyway, in a nutshell the idea is to capture the list with something akin to `std::forward_as_tuple` and then perform the operation on the resulting tuple elements...

Comment: Too bad there is no easy way to fold over operator types in C++

Comment: @Yakk `bool r = true; int _[]{(r = r && t != std::get<I>(*this), 0)...}; return r;`

Comment: @Oktalist I mean "for each operator, generate this code".

Answer (score 4):

We can get this syntax:

```
int main() {
  if (foo *in* std::tie(bar, baz)) {
  }
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44cadfe75178ddf7).

It also works with C arrays or std containers or the like on the right hand side of `*in*`.

This should be zero overhead after the optimizer gets its teeth into it.

Negating is just:

```
  if (!(foo *in* std::tie(bar, baz)))
```

as I don't think a special case is a good plan.  If you want the `foo *not in* std::tie(bar, baz))` syntax, see bottom of this post.

---

First, a named operator library:

```
namespace named_operator {
  template<class D>struct make_operator{constexpr make_operator(){}};

  template<class T, char, class O> struct half_apply { T&& lhs; };

  template<class Lhs, class Op>
  half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op> operator*( Lhs&& lhs, make_operator<Op> ) {
    return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)};
  }

  template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
  auto operator*( half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs )
  -> decltype( invoke( std::declval<Lhs>(), Op{}, std::declval<Rhs>() ) )
  {
    return invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
  }
}
```

which is about 12 lines long, and makes named operators easy.

Now we make a named operator.
    namespace my_ns {
      constexpr struct in_tag:named_operator::make_operator {} in {};
    }
    using my_ns::in;
It needs an action.  The C++17 version is easy:

```
namespace my_ns {
  // foo in tuple support:
  template<class T, class...Args>
  bool invoke( T const& lhs, in_tag, std::tuple<Args...> const& rhs ) {
    return std::apply( [&](auto&&...args){
      return (false || ... || (lhs == args));
    }, rhs);
  }
  // foo in container support:
  template<class T, class Container>
  bool invoke( T const& lhs, in_tag, Container const& rhs ) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    auto it = std::find( begin(rhs), end(rhs), lhs );
    return it != end(rhs);
  }
}
```

The C++11 tuple support version is a bit trickier, because of the lack of `std::apply` and fold expansion:

```
namespace my_ns {
  // tuple support:
  template<class T, class...Args, std::size_t...Is>
  bool invoke( T const& lhs, in_tag, std::tuple<Args...> const& rhs, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    bool retval = false;
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{ 0,(void(
      retval = retval || (lhs == std::get<Is>(rhs))
    ),0)... };
    return retval;
  }
  template<class T, class...Args>
  bool invoke( T const& lhs, in_tag, std::tuple<Args...> const& rhs ) {
    return invoke(lhs, in_tag{}, rhs, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{} );
  }
  // container support is identical to C++17 version
}
```

---

As mentioned above, if you want

```
  if (foo *not in* std::tie(bar, baz))
```

I can do it.

Add a `not_in` operator:

```
namespace my_ns {
  constexpr struct not_in_tag:named_operator::make_operator<not_in_tag> {} not_in {};
}
using my_ns::not_in;
```

We then define `!` that toggles between them:

```
namespace my_ns {
  constexpr not_in_tag operator!(in_tag){return {};}
  constexpr in_tag operator!(not_in_tag){return {};}
|
```

and what the `not_in` operator does:

```
namespace my_ns {
  template<class T, class Rhs>
  bool invoke( T const& lhs, not_in_tag, Rhs const& rhs ) {
    return !invoke(lhs, in_tag{}, rhs );
  }
}
```

for `invoke`.

Now we get

```
  if (foo *not in* std::tie(bar, baz)) {
    std::cout << "foo not in {bar,baz}\n";
  }
  if (foo *not in* std::make_tuple(bar, baz, 3)) {
    std::cout << "foo not in {bar,baz, 3}\n";
  }
```

or

```
  if (foo *not_in* std::tie(bar, baz)) {
    std::cout << "foo not in {bar,baz}\n";
  }
```

or

```
  if (foo *!in* std::tie(bar, baz)) {
    std::cout << "foo not in {bar,baz}\n";
  }
```

whichever you want.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24ad8087a6eb4c21)

Comment: `x <in> y` would have been better.

Comment: I have a solution that doesn't use any libraries!

Comment: @MatthewRoh The entire "library" used above is in the post itself, and is about 12 lines long.

Comment: So Did you make the library.

Comment: @matt Yes, I wrote it for a different SO post lost to time.

Comment: @Yakk That looks complex, but I will try to understand.

Comment: @Yakk You do not need not_in separately. You just need to do `#define not_in *!in*` and You can exclude the asterisks.

Comment: @MatthewRoh Using the preprocessor is something I avoid unless it yields significant benefits.  I see little benefit here.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advise you not to pollute code with fancy stuff unless needed.

The following C++14 solution offers an infix syntax as in Python, in case you have more than two values to compare to:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename... T>
struct in_checker : std::tuple<T...> {
    using std::tuple<T...>::tuple;
    template <typename U, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr bool contains(U const& u, std::index_sequence<Is...>) const {
        for (auto b : {std::get<Is>(*this) == u...})
            if (b) return true;
        return false;
    }
    template <typename U>
    constexpr bool contains(U const& u) const {
        return contains(u, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});}
};

template <typename U, typename... T>
constexpr bool operator==(U const& u, in_checker<T...> const& in) {
    return in.contains(u);}
template <typename U, typename... T>
constexpr bool operator!=(U const& u, in_checker<T...> const& in) {
    return !(u == in);}

template <typename... T>
constexpr in_checker<T...> in(T const&... t) {return std::tie(t...);}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int t = 2;
    if (t == in(1, 2, 3))
        std::cout << "Congrats";
    if (t != in(1, 3, 4))
        std::cout << "... again!";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f254b5baa3882863).

Comment: The reason I want to pollute my code with this is because it's difficult to grok code that has a crap load of these checks. I'm looking to improve readability of this code. Your solution might be uglier than python but it's definitely easier to read than the big ass if statement it will replace.

Comment: @guidoism: It's *two clauses*. That's hardly "big ass".

Comment: @NicolBolas Two tiny clauses in my example for clarity, the real code has more and the constants are long and take up the entire line each so this is a many line if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Not really elegant, I suppose, but you can write a simple `isIn()` template function

```
template <typename T>
bool isIn (const T & val, const std::set<T> & s)
 { return s.cend() != s.find(val); }
```

and the following is a simple case of use when `T` is `int`

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
bool isIn (const T & val, const std::set<T> & s)
 { return s.cend() != s.find(val); }

int main ()
 {
   int  bar = 5;
   int  baz = 3;

   int  foo = 0;

   if ( false == isIn(foo, {bar, baz}) )
      std::cout << foo << " isn\'t in set" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << foo << " is in set" << std::endl;

   foo = 3;

   if ( false == isIn(foo, {bar, baz}) )
      std::cout << foo << " isn\'t in set" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << foo << " is in set" << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

**--- post edit edit --**

@guidoism: I think your question is interesting in a more general way but, if you must only check `somelongmethodname()` against values of an enum, I think a readable solution could be the good old `switch`

```
 using SomeReallyLongNamespace::AndAnotherSubClassname;

 switch ( somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname() )
  {
     case A_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME:
     case ANOTHER_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME:
        // do nothing (or something, if you like)
        break;

     default:
        // do something
        break;
  }
```

Comment: There's already a much simpler way to do this with a `set`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37887522/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee - I see; really elegant; It's a solution better than mine to answer the question (I suppose) but I propose mine because don't modify the set.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, so you wouldn't have to create another temporary `set` if you wanted to do some of this craziness when all that needed to be done was do `if(foo != bar && foo != baz)`. What a frustrating question when all of our answers are by definition going to be worse than what's already in the question :(

Comment: @JonathanMee - I suppose use `if (foo != bar && foo != baz)` it's simpler with only two elements in the set but I find the question interesting thinking at a set of big number of elements or at a not constant set. P.s.: sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 1):

I do like the elegant simplicity of the Python syntax:

```
if foo not in {bar, baz}
```

In a scripting language minimalistic code is the highest good. But under the hood that line is going to:

1. Construct a simple container something like C++'s `initializer_list`
2. Insert references to `bar` and `baz` into the container
3. Get a reference to the 1<sup>st</sup> item in the container
4. Compare that reference to `foo` if equal destroy the container and jump to the `false` branch
5. Get the next reference in the container
6. Compare that reference to `foo` if equal destroy the container and jump to the `false` branch
7. Destroy the container and fall into the `true` branch

In C++ the highest good is speed so let's look at the way that we're forced to do it in C++:

```
if(foo != bar && foo != baz)
```

1. Compare `foo` to `bar` if equal jump to the `false` branch
2. Compare `foo` to `baz` if equal jump to the `false` branch
3. Fall through to the `true` branch

This is not to say that a good compiler couldn't optimize away the container in the Python `if`-statement, but if these variables represent objects with differing construction rules that may be all but impossible. If C++ does grace us with this syntax, I'll be the second to adopt it, right after you. But for now the construction of a temporary container to veil individual comparisons is a poor decision for 2 reasons:

**1. The unintended cost of container construction may not be optimized away

 2. Since there are not standard provided keywords the cost to the reader to figure out what's happening will outweigh the elegance gained by using a container



So for now the best solution is still old reliable: `if(foo != bar && foo != baz)`**

---

That's not say we can't use a container in C++ though, given the type of `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` is `int` you could do either of these great evils:

1. `if(basic_string<int>{bar, baz}.find(foo) == -1)`
2. `if(set<int>{bar, baz}.insert(foo).second)`
3. `if(!set<int>{bar, baz}.count(foo))`

**EDIT:**

After seeing your edit to your question it should be said that even if you could use the Python syntax that only saves you: *characters-in-`foo` + 4 characters* Given the code:

```
if (somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname() != SomeReallyLongNamespace::AndAnotherSubClassname::A_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME &&
    somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname() != SomeReallyLongNamespace::AndAnotherSubClassname::ANOTHER_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME)
```

If what your saying is that you have `public`, `static` variables like this:

```
namespace SomeReallyLongNamespace {
    struct AndAnotherSubClassname{
        static const auto A_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME = 13;
        static const auto ANOTHER_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME = 42;
    };
}
```

Then a [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)-statement will eliminate a ton of typing, not just here but everywhere within the scope that the `using` is defined:

```
using namespace SomeReallyLongNamespace;

if (somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname() != AndAnotherSubClassname::A_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME &&
    somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname() != AndAnotherSubClassname::ANOTHER_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME)
```

Next presuming that `somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname()` is a `const` method the best practice is to mirror it's return in a constant temporary, thereby only requiring you call the method once, again improving our code:

```
using SomeReallyLongNamespace::AndAnotherSubClassname;
const auto& foo = somelongvariablename.somelongmethodname();

 if(foo != AndAnotherSubClassname::A_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME && foo != AndAnotherSubClassname::ANOTHER_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME)
```

There obviously are a couple conditions there, but I'd say that if you can pull this off your concern has greatly improved your code to the point that you'd only save *7 characters* with the Python syntax, returning the old faithful C++ syntax to a viable contender.

Comment: Congrats for packing it into one if statement but dang that is hacky!

Comment: @vu1p3n0x As I said: "Newer... not better." There are countless other evil ways we could do this with `pair`s, `tuple`s, `set`s, `switch`es, turnaries and the list goes on, but it doesn't get better.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ugh. Of course you're right. I don't know what I was thinking. I've edited but it doesn't clean up near as nice when I do it legally.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Snap! I got it shorter: `if(set<int>{bar, baz}.count(foo))` Pretty certain that's as good as anyone will do. Without boatloads of supplemental code.

Comment: I heard There are some C++17 functions and classes for that.

Comment: @MatthewRoh I'm going to say there are not. You've seen some of the brightest folks on http://stackoverflow.com post answers here, if anyone would know of a C++17 addendum it would be them. As such I don't believe that such a thing exists in C++17. If you felt like reading through the draft though, I'd welcome an answer!

Comment: I have seen `any`. We could use it though.

Comment: @MatthewRoh o.O I'm pretty sure `any` is just a better version of Boost's `variant` type. It's helpful for storing multiple types in an array, but I don't see how that benefits us here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
initializer_list<T> in(initializer_list<T> K)
{
    return K;
}
template<typename T>
bool operator !=(T A, initializer_list<T> B)
{
    bool R = true;
    for (auto E : B)R = R && (A != E);
    return R;
}

int main()
{
    if (1 != in({2,3,4}))
    {
        cout << "Wow" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in this way we can make the code more readable like
`1 != in({2,3,4})`

## EDIT:

Found a more readable way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
initializer_list<T> o(initializer_list<T> K)
{
    return K;
}
class not_i
{

};
class not_i_helper1
{
public:
    int S;
};
not_i_helper1 operator<(int A, not_i P)
{
    not_i_helper1 K;
    K.S = A;
    return K;
}
bool operator>(not_i_helper1 S, initializer_list<int> B)
{
    bool R = true;
    for (auto E : B)R = R && (S.S != E);
    return R;
}
not_i not_in;
int main()
{
    if (1 < not_in > o({ 2,3,4 }))
    {
        cout << "Success!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Huh?" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

now we can use `1 < not_in > o({ 2,3,4 })`

Comment: If there is something to improve, Tell me!

Comment: also you can get some idea in
http://pfultz2.com/blog/2015/02/01/adding-in-operator/

Comment: (it uses a external library though)

Comment: This is similar, but uses no other library!

Answer (score 0):

If your case is really simple you can just do this:

```
for (auto& e : {bar, baz})
  if (foo == e)
  { /* found */ };
```

note, as is, this doesn't have a way to say if isn't in there.

Comment: Overloadable `operator!:` -- quick, to the propsal machine :-)

Answer (score -1):

This one is a one-liner on my 15" 16:9 laptop :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    for(std::set<int> omg({1, 2, 3, 4}); omg.find(42) == omg.cend(); ) { std::cout << "There's no Answer." << std::endl; break; }
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB The for loop is a bit concerning, but I do think that a `set` is the "best" intuition here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37887522/2642059 Maybe I should say "worst" intuition since the simple `if`-statement in the question is the best... I wouldn't want people thinking that this is a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanMee, know a better way to quickly create a local binding in `let`less C++?

Comment: Can you ask that a different way, I'm not sure what you're saying. `set` is in my opinion the best way to do this though. I use `if(set<int>{bar, baz}.insert(foo).second)` in my answer.

Comment: I'm not speaking of `set`, it's about the `for` loop. I've used it as a quick `let`-like construct.
Though, after thoughtful consideration the exact implementation would require a `{}`-block anyway, and then one can simply create local bindings as the first statements to that block.

Comment: So, I had assumed that you meant to type `set`, that seems to not be the case. Can you explain what you mean by: "a `let`-like construct"?

Comment: Something that creates local bindings, what else? `(let ((tmp (set 1 2 3 4))) (if (eq? (end tmp) (find tmp 42)) (print "There's no Answer")))`

Comment: I'm gonna guess from the syntax that you're trying to write Haskell code? C++ can use `insert` or `count` to avoid referencing the `set` more than once. So there's really no need for Haskell's `let`

Comment: It's not Haskell, don't you see the parens? ;) Good point for `insert`.